# navigational/home/end keys are not working in content editable div - FF browser

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, contenteditable

I have editable div(contenteditable=true) and I am dynamically adding innerHTML content to this div.

I observed that 'navigational arrows', 'home' and 'end' keys not working in this div. This is specifically for firefox browser only. However its working in chorme browser.

Please suggest your pointers.

Comment: Have you got a demo page?